# jQuery click toggle animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm trying to learn how to use jQuery, and I've stumbled upon a problem. First off, I will show you the part of the code that causes the problem.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="button"><p class="scroll" onclick="location.href='#ed';">Education</p></div>
<div id="button"><p class="scroll" onclick="location.href='#wxp';">Work Experience</p></div>
<div id="button"><p class="scroll" onclick="location.href='#oact';">Other Activities</p></div>
<div id="button"><p class="scroll" onclick="window.open('cv.pdf','mywindow');">View as PDF</p></div>
<div id="arrow_container"><div class="arrow" id="down"></div></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#arrow_container").toggle(
  function () {
    $("#nav").animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);
      }, function () {
    $("#nav").animate({marginTop:"-100px"}, 200);
  });
});
```

I want the div `#nav`, which is initially positioned partially outside of the screen, to move down when div `#arrow_container` is clicked. Then when `#arrow_container` is clicked again I want `#nav` to move up, to its original position.

At the moment, non of this happens. Can you tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it?

EDIT: [a jsfiddle with the code, including some css](http://jsfiddle.net/5vfkn/)

EDIT 2: The problem seems to be solved. Also thanks to someone whose username I forgot and answer has been deleted, but he had some great tips! Thank you!

Comment: Can you attempt to recreate your issue in a jsfiddle, or provide some CSS or something so we can see how you're positioning #nav?

Comment: Also if you're starting to learn jQuery, I would suggest not using toggle as it is no longer included in the latest versions of jQuery.

Comment: @A.V nope, 1.8 it was depreciated as of 1.9 it is no longer included. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: That's not entirely true, there were two [different implementations](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11786) of using `.toggle()`, the [toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) is deprecated, while the standard [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is still fully supported.

Comment: @idrumgood I've added a jsfiddle in the main post, I hope it clears things up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#arrow_container").click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( $(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
        $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"-100px"}, 200);                            
    } else {
        $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("isDown");
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/us6sohyg/5/

Comment: you can also use toggleClass('isDown') after the if statements to remove add and remove class redundancy

Comment: @BenSewards Thanks, I updated my code.  Also added the suggestion from Timotheus Triebl.

Answer (score 4):

for me that didn't work to 100% i had to edit a stop() event before every animate.
so:

```
$("#arrow_container").click( function(event){
event.preventDefault();
if ($(this).hasClass("isDown") ) {
    $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200);          
    $(this).removeClass("isDown");
} else {
    $("#nav").stop().animate({marginTop:"-100px"}, 200);   
    $(this).addClass("isDown");
}
return false;
});
```